# Use of break in Scala With Return Value

Tags: scala, functional-programming, break

I have the below requirement where I am checking whether a value is greater than 10 or not and based on that I will break, otherwise I will return a String. Below is my code:

```
import scala.util.control.Breaks._

class BreakInScala {
  val breakException = new RuntimeException("Break happened")

  def break = throw breakException

  def callMyFunc(x: Int): String = breakable(myFunc(x))

  def myFunc(x: Int): String = {
    if (x > 10) {
      "I am fine"
    } else {
      break
    }
  }
}
```

Now what is the happening is that I am getting the error message saying **"type mismatch; found : Unit required: String"** The reason is :

```
def breakable(op: => Unit)
```

But then how I will write a function which can return value as well as break if required?

Comment: Imagine a situation when the very first iteration was breaken. What should you return as a result for callMyFunc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Scala compiler can evaluate that a branch throws an exception and not use it to form a minimum bound for the return type, but not if you move the throwing code out in a method: since it can be overridden, the compiler cannot be sure it will actually never return.

Your usage of the Break constructs seems confused: it already provides a break method, there is no need to provide your own, unless you want to throw your exception instead, which would make using Break unnecessary.

You are left with a couple of options then, since I believe usage of Break is unnecessary in your case.

1) Simply throw an exception on failure

```
def myFunc(x: Int): String = {
  if (x > 10) {
    "I am fine"
  } else {
    throw new RuntimeException("Break happened")
  }
}

def usemyFunc(): Unit = {
  try {
    println("myFunc(11) is " + myFunc(11))
    println("myFunc(5) is " + myFunc(5))
  } catch {
    case e: Throwable => println("myFunc failed with " + e)
  }
}
```

2) Use the Try class (available from Scala 2.10) to return either a value or an exception. This differs from the previous suggestion because it forces the caller to inspect the result and check whether a value is available or not, but makes using the result a bit more cumbersome

```
import scala.util.Try

def myFunc(x: Int): Try[String] = {
  Try {
    if (x > 10) {
      "I am fine"
    } else {
      throw new RuntimeException("Break happened")
    }
  }
}

def useMyFunc(): Unit = {
  myFunc match {
    case Try.Success(s) => println("myFunc succeded with " + s)
    case Try.Failure(e) => println("myFunc failed with " + e)
  }
}
```

3) If the thrown exception isn't relevant, you can use the Option class instead.
You can see how the multiple ways of working with Options relate to each other in
this great [cheat sheet](http://blog.tmorris.net/posts/scalaoption-cheat-sheet/).

```
def myFunc(x: Int): Option[String] = {
  if (x > 10) {
    Some("I am fine") /* Some(value) creates an Option containing value */
  } else {
    None /* None represents an Option that has no value */ 
  }
}

/* There are multiple ways to work with Option instances.
   One of them is using pattern matching. */

def useMyFunc(): Unit = {
  myFunc(10) match {
    case Some(s) => println("myFunc succeded with " + s)
    case None => println("myFunc failed")
  }
}

/* Another one is using the map, flatMap, getOrElse, etc methods.
   They usually take a function as a parameter, which is only executed
   if some condition is met.

   map only runs the received function if the Option contains a value,
   and passes said value as a parameter to it. It then takes the result
   of the function application, and creates a new Option containing it.

   getOrElse checks if the Option contains a value. If it does, it is returned
   directly. If it does not, then the result of the function passed to it
   is returned instead.

   Chaining map and getOrElse is a common idiom meaning roughly 'transform the value
   contained in this Option using this code, but if there is no value, return whatever
   this other piece of code returns instead'.
*/

def useMyFunc2(): Unit = {
  val toPrint = myFunc(10).map{ s =>
    "myFunc(10) succeded with " + s
  }.getOrElse{
    "myFunc(10) failed"
  }

  /* toPrint now contains a message to be printed, depending on whether myFunc
     returned a value or not. The Scala compiler is smart enough to infer that
     both code paths return String, and make toPrint a String as well. */

  println(toPrint)
}
```

Comment: Option 1 and 2, I can understand. But understanding option 3 is seems difficult to me.

Comment: I'll try to explain it in a bit more detail.

Comment: I updated the Option part a bit, see if it helps you.

Answer (score 2):

This is a slightly odd way of doing things (throwing an exception), an alternative way of doing this might be to define a "partial function" (a function which is only defined only a specific subset of it's domain a bit like this:

```
scala> val partial = new PartialFunction[Int, String] {
       | def apply(i : Int) = "some string"
       | def isDefinedAt(i : Int) = i < 10
       }

partial: PartialFunction[Int, String] = <function1>
```

Once you've defined the function, you can then "lift" it into an Option of type Int, by doing the following:

```
scala> val partialLifted = partial.lift
partialOpt: Int => Option[String] = <function1>
```

Then, if you call the function with a value outside your range, you'll get a "None" as a return value, otherwise you'll get your string return value.  This makes it much easier to apply flatMaps/ getOrElse logic to the function without having to throw exceptions all over the place...

```
scala> partialLifted(45)
res7: Option[String] = None

scala> partialLifted(10)
res8:  Option[String] = Some(return string)
```

IMO, this is a slightly more functional way of doing things...hope it helps

Comment: Sorry, I got the range the wrong way around there - but the idea is exactly the same, just modify the expression which evaluates to Boolean(True) within the isDefinedAt function.

Comment: Also, where I say lift to an "Option of type Int" I mean Option[String] of course...oops!